# graph with largest eigenvalue at most 2

Tags: graph-theory

I encounter this exercise in the chapter of 'Line Graphs and Eigenvalues', GTM207-Algebraic Graph Theory by Godsil & Royle.

I know the answer should be "The only connected graphs having largest eigenvalue 2 are the following graphs (the number of vertices is one more than the index given)."[image]

But I cannot work out the proof of it. Can anyone help me with this? Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints on how to proceed:

1. If $H$ is a subgraph of $G$, then $\lambda(H) \leq \lambda(G)$. If $G$ is connected and $H$ is a proper subgraph, we have strict inequality.

In particular, any cycle has largest eigenvalue $2$, so if $G$ contains a cycle as a proper subgraph, then $\lambda(G) > 2$.

Which trees have largest eigenvalue $2$?

2. If $\Delta$ is the maximum degree, $\bar{d}$ the average degree, then $\max(\sqrt{\Delta}, \bar{d}) \leq \lambda(G) \leq \Delta$.

This will tell you that $2 \leq \Delta \leq 4$. When $\Delta = 4$, there is only one tree with largest eigenvalue $2$ (I will leave this for you to check).

When $\Delta = 3$, you may verify that the graphs you have shown do have largest eigenvalue $2$. Except for $E_6$, $E_7$, and $E_8$, why does a tree with exactly one vertex of degree $3$ not have largest eigenvalue $2$? What if it has at least $3$ vertices of degree $3$? (these are repeated applications of my first hint)

When $\Delta = 2$, what kind of tree is this?

Comment: Thanks for your hints! Following your hints, I think the maximum degree can be $2, 3$ or $4$. However, I'm still confused about a few things: (1) How can we cross out the case when $\Delta= 4$? (2) I don't quite understand what the eigenvalues will be if there are two vertices of maximum degree.

Comment: When $\Delta = 4$, $\sqrt{\Delta} = 2$ so $\lambda(G) \geq 2$. This rules out $\Delta = 4$. What have you gotten from the first hint?

Comment: But $\lambda(G) \geq 2$ contains the case $\lambda=2$

Comment: Oh I see, I misread the question! Nevertheless, you can use my hints to classify the graphs with largest eigenvalue strictly less than $2$. Then consider that every proper subgraph of $G$ has largest eigenvalue strictly less than $2$.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more detailed! I hope this is more clear.